# Getting fatal error showing time out exception when trying to run kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, timeoutexception

```
[2021-04-08 02:53:18,713] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,182] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 18000ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,288] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,288] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,290] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,295] ****ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING**
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1881)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:441)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:466)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,300] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,308] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,309] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,310] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-04-08 02:53:33,311] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the zk server is not started. Kafka needs zookeeper, you need to download and start zookeeper before start kafka server.